# JWT And Routes Symfony3

Tags: php, symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

I have two firewalls in my **security.yml** file:

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern:  ^/api/v1/auth$
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: fos_userbundle
            form_login:
                check_path:               /api/v1/auth
                success_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler:          lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
                require_previous_session: false

        api:
            pattern:   ^/api/v1
            stateless: true
            provider: fos_userbundle
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
```

And two routes in **AuthController**:

```
/**
 * @param ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher
 *
 * @Rest\Post("/auth")
 * @Rest\RequestParam(name="email", strict=true)
 * @Rest\RequestParam(name="password", strict=true)
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function postTokenAuthAction (ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher)
{
    if($user = $this->getUser()) {
        return $user->getRoles();
    }

    $email = $paramFetcher->get('email');
    $password = $paramFetcher->get('password');

    /** @var User|null $user */
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneByEmail($email);

    if(!$user || !$this->get('security.password_encoder')->isPasswordValid($user, $password)) {
        throw new HttpException(403, $this->get('translator')->trans('auth.error'));
    }

    $token = $this->get('lexik_jwt_authentication.encoder')->encode([
        'email' => $user->getEmail()
    ]);

    return ['access_token' => $token];

}

/**
 * @param ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher
 *
 * @Rest\Post("/auth/check")
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function postCheckLoginAction (ParamFetcherInterface $paramFetcher)
{
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $this->getUser();

            if (!$user) {
        throw $this->createAccessDeniedException();
    }

    return $user->getRoles();

}
```

I sent POST request in `/api/v1/auth` with POST `email=&password=` parameters for get access_token. But I got 401 error "Bad credentials".

Ok. Next I'm changed parameter `pattern`in `login` firewall to `^/api/v1/auth` and `form_login.check_path` to `/api/v1/auth/check` and it's works fine. 
Now I can login by email and password and get access_token.

But   route `/api/v1/auth/check` now returns **Bad credentials**. It's trying to authorize me by **email** and **password** in this route, but I want that it try authorize by **Authorization** header.

Why it works wrong?

Eventually, I want send `email` and `password` to `/api/v1/auth`  for getting `access token`, and next send `access_token` to `/api/v1/auth/check` and get user roles.

Comment: email=&password= <- it's a GET method syntax

Comment: I know. It's just example for question. I'm sending this parameters in POST body.

Comment: which version of jwt are you using?

Comment: stable 2.0.2. Actually, I think that is symfony security.yml trouble, not JWT Bundle

Answer (score 0):

Do you try with _username and _password (With low-dash) instead the ones that you use?, by default this is the fields that stores this values.

I hope this works for you